# objective C undefined symbols for architechture i386, i dont understand this error

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am debuting in objective C, and im trying to do a simple password generator for iOS.
In this snippet of code, I try to create a random string with letters and number. Then I try to show this string by a `NSLog` (to see if it works)

When i run the program, ive got this error :

[image]

I created 2 files, there is my `viewcontroller.m` :

[image]

And my `viewcontroller.h` :

[image]

Can you help me?

Comment: And my viewcontroller .h :
http://images4.hiboox.com/images/1213/30eee413ffc3806acbe32e2017045909.png

Comment: after doing code modifications as suggested below, if the error still persists, close xcode..navigate to path cd /Users/macos/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData and remove all files there using Terminal. Relauch Xcode and run again. It works for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something is mighty hosed in your project somehow.

- `start` is basically the entry point to your program;  it is a part of the dyld initialization and is what jumps to `main()`.   (Try setting a symbolic breakpoint on `start` and then run your app -- it is a tiny routine in `dyld` that figures out where `main` is and tail-calls to it which is why you never see it in backtraces unless something has gone terribly, wildly, wrong).
- `arc4random` is a part of the C standard library.   It should always be available.

The only thing clue I see is that link line uses `-nostdlib`.  That seems odd.  Go to your Build Settings and make sure **Link with Standard Libraries** is turned on.  If it isn't, what happened and what else might have changed?

Note that there are a slew of other problems with the code.

Those non-ivar declarations in the header file are going to cause problems;  they will become duplicate symbols the first time you #import that file into another compilation unit (another .m file).

The `@interface UIViewController()` is not necessary (nor should you ever declare methods on system classes).

Comment: -nostdlib is definitely part of the problem here. "Do not use the standard system startup files or libraries when linking. No startup files and only the libraries you specify are passed to the linker" - that means no arc4random(), and no start().

Answer (score -1):

Hi Please do following steps
1) Restart XCode.
2) Please check if you added quartz code framework.
3) Clean and build.

Please remove semicolon(;) after statement in **-(NSString *)generer:(int)len** in .m file.

In previous app i also got same issue.
Hope this will help.

Answer (score -2):

You have used c++ code in your program arc4random() which is undefined symbols for architechture i386, i dont understand this error.

To fix this just add ,`#include <stdlib.h>` at header .this should work.